# Will rust optimise a match statement containing another match statement that uses the same input as the first?

Tags: rust

I have some enums and all these enums contain some data in common, so I have extracted the common part and combined the common and type specific parts in a struct:

```
struct Data{
    common_data: bool,
    type_specific_data: Enum
}
enum Enum {
    A(i32),
    B(bool)
}
```

I have a main loop that iterates through the vector of Data and dispatches a `run` function depending on the type. It doesn't use dynamic dispatch or anything clever, I just have a manual match statement that dispatches the function.

The problem is, these functions need both the type_specific_data and the common_data.

```
fn main() {
    let mut d = Data {
        common_data: true,
        type_specific_data: Enum::A(42)
    };
    match d.type_specific_data {
        Enum::A(_) => run_a(&mut d),
        Enum::B(_) => run_b(&mut d)
    }
}
```

The `run` functions:

```
fn run_a(a: &mut Data) {
    //do stuff with common_data
    //...
    //do stuff with type_specific_data
    let a = match &mut a.type_specific_data {
        Enum::A(a) => a,
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
    *a = *a+1;
}

fn run_b(b: &mut Data) {
    //do stuff with common_data
    //...
    //do stuff with type_specific_data
    let b = match &mut b.type_specific_data {
        Enum::B(b) => b,
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
    *b = !*b;
}
```

As the type_specific_data is matched in the main function, will rust be clever enough to realise it does not need a conditional branch in the run function?

This is a minimal reproducible example. The real code has many more enums, and the dispatched functions contain a lot of logic acting on both the common_data and the type_specific_data. I want to factor things into functions for better code organisation.

Full code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=499ffb25e34935b65944ea3354bf8ef3

Comment: Not sure why you can't just define `run` and avoid all this headache, since all of it would be optimizations none of it is guaranteed.

Comment: @cafce25 I'm not sure what you mean? I could have a single run function and put the match statement in there (like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1407897c58f5b8f13e2545cc263d30a4), but the amount of code in each match arm would be a lot as the run functions do a lot of work. I need to organise the code and have that logic in its own function. If I put functions in the match arms, I'm back to square 1. The functions can't accept both the common_data and type_specific_data as that would need two mutable references to the same thing.

Comment: Well if its for organization purposes I get it but "The functions can't accept both the `common_data` and `type_specific_data` as that would need two mutable references to the same thing." is simply [not true](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7ec2d03e7ec5b1c84b82bb444ed9d0a) since `common_data` and `type_specific_data` are different fields of a struct and Rust does partial borrows just fine.

Comment: I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @ cafce25 Oh damn, you're right. In my larger example this gave an error, but I must have misunderstood the real problem.
Having the `run` functions contain two arguments, one for the `common_data` and one for the `type_specific_data` data certainly makes sense then.
I guess the only downside is a cosmetic one. The `run` functions look better if they accept a single argument representing one thing, instead of two arguments representing one thing.
But that downside does not outweigh the ugliness of the `unreachable!() ` match arm.

Comment: @Stargateur
I would still like an answer to the optimisation details of match statements in this configuration. While cafce has proposed an alternative solution, I may keep my code as it is unless it is certainly not optimised out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it gets optimized highly depends on the actual functions, if both `run_a` and `run_b` are inlined by the compiler I'd say it's likely the interior check is optimized away. If they're not inlined, that optimization is hard to make, you need the check in `main` to determine the path to take there and you need the check in `run_a/b` to produce sound code in case the function gets misused.

The only way to know for sure is to analyze the assembly produced. For your example code that is:

```asm
main:
    ret
```

So yes the checks along with all of the rest of the code are optimized away.
If you add some `black_box` calls to stop some of the optimizations you'll see that indeed the interior check is optimized away if the function is inlined and not if it's not inlined.

```rust
use std::hint::black_box;
struct Data{
    common_data: bool,
    type_specific_data: Enum
}
enum Enum {
    A(i32),
    B(bool)
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut d = black_box(Data {
        common_data: true,
        type_specific_data: Enum::A(42)
    });
    match d.type_specific_data {
        Enum::A(_) => run_a(&mut d),
        Enum::B(_) => run_b(&mut d)
    }
    black_box(d);
}

#[inline(never)]
fn run_a(a: &mut Data) {
    //do stuff with common_data
    //...
    //do stuff with type_specific_data
    let a = match &mut a.type_specific_data {
        Enum::A(a) => a,
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
    *a = *a+1;
}

fn run_b(b: &mut Data) {
    //do stuff with common_data
    //...
    //do stuff with type_specific_data
    let b = match &mut b.type_specific_data {
        Enum::B(b) => b,
        _ => unreachable!()
    };
    *b = !*b;
}
```

produces 2 conditional jumps:

1. the one in `main`

   ```asm
       cmp     byte ptr [rsp + 8], 0
       je      .LBB0_1
   ```
2. the one in the not inlined `run_a`

   ```asm
       cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
       jne     .LBB1_2
   ```

The one from `run_b` is optimized away since it got inlined.

The complete generated assembly:

```asm
example::main:
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 8], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], 42
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 16], 1
        lea     rax, [rsp + 8]
        cmp     byte ptr [rsp + 8], 0
        je      .LBB0_1
        xor     byte ptr [rsp + 9], 1
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        call    example::run_a
.LBB0_3:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], eax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        lea     rax, [rsp + 24]
        add     rsp, 40
        ret

example::run_a:
        push    rax
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
        jne     .LBB1_2
        inc     dword ptr [rdi + 4]
        pop     rax
        ret
.LBB1_2:
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_2]
        mov     esi, 40
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::panicking::panic@GOTPCREL]
        ud2

.L__unnamed_1:
        .ascii  "internal error: entered unreachable code"

.L__unnamed_3:
        .ascii  "/app/example.rs"

.L__unnamed_2:
        .quad   .L__unnamed_3
        .asciz  "\017\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\036\000\000\000\016\000\000"
```

[rust.godbolt.com](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/fd19jY688)